# How to create underbrace with nothing on top

Tags: braces

This will be a short one:
I want the underbrace to be extended as much as I want, without writing something on top. So far I got:

```
$\underbrace{\hspace{12pt}}_{\vec{F_p} = \frac{-{e}^2}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0\,{\vec{r}}^{\,2}}\,\frac{\vec{r}}{r}}$.
```

The brace has still shrunk

Comment: I'd say just increase`12pt`, but I have a feeling that this is an XY problem. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I want to export the graphics into another graphic design program. I don't want to have this written in some sort of text. Just some large brace, which width I can control and only the formula beneath.

Comment: Nevermind, increasing the number of \hspace resolves the Problem. Thank you for pointing to the obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a phantom of the subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\emptyunderbrace}[1]{%
  {\underbrace{\hphantom{\scriptstyle#1}}_{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\emptyunderbrace{\vec{F_p} = \frac{-{e}^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0{\vec{r}}^{\,2}}\frac{\vec{r}}{r}}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]